# Slim Route Passing to another file Returning Value

Tags: php, routes, logic, slim

I have a **folder structure** like this :

```
|/app 
|-/db/users.php
|/Slim
|/vendor
|index.php
```

and inside `index.php`:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Slim\App();

$app->get('/{action}/{type}/{props}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    $jenis_user = strtolower($args['type']);
    $aksi = strtolower($args['action']);
    $prop = strtolower($args['props']);

    $target_loc = "";

    if($aksi == 'get'){

        // the parameter is using the following format
        // action=XX&type=YY&props=ZZ;
        $target_loc = "./app/db/users.php?action=". $aksi . "&type=" . $jenis_user . "&props=" . $prop ;

        // #Tips :: data extracted are in Array Format ::
        $file = file_get_contents($target_loc);
        $response->write(json_encode($file));

    }

    return $response;
});
```

My purpose is to get an integer value returned if I use the following path into the browser:

```
http://api.myweb.com/get/seller/totalNumber
```

But it seems the way I wrote the routing of passing parameter is mistaken: I got a warning of

> Warning: file_get_contents(./app/db/users.php?action=get&type=seller&props=totalnumber): failed to open stream

How could I fix it?

Comment: You need to give us the contents of `app/db/users.php` ... On a side note this is terrible design. Your dependency should be a class, then you can simply ask for an output from the class and jsonify it.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get a file with the name `users.php?action=get&type=seller&props=totalnumber` which doesn't exist, in the `file://` protocol, when you really what to do this you need to extra specify the `http` or `https` protocol like this:

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://example.com/users.php?x=y');
```

and it will succeed.

**Notice**: this is a bad structur, it would be better when you define a function or class for this, it could be like this:

**functions.php**

```
function getUsers($type, $props) {
    // do your stuff
    return $yourUsers;
}
```

**index.php** or route file

```
include 'functions.php'; // include the functions

$app = new Slim\App();
$app->get('/{action}/{type}/{props}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    $jenis_user = strtolower($args['type']);
    $aksi = strtolower($args['action']);
    $prop = strtolower($args['props']);

    if($aksi == 'get'){

        $users = getUsers($jenis_user, $prop); // execute the function to collect the user
        $response->write(json_encode($users ));
    }

    return $response;
});
```

Then you wouldn't need the `file_get_contents()`.